# MYSQL query producing duplicate rows one one of the JOIN's

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, join

EDIT:  Huge thanks to Sergey for solving this problem for me.  As soon as he gets it put up as an answer I will mark is and answered.

My query is as shown below:

```
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    songsID, song_name, artist_band_name, author, song_artwork, song_file,
    genre, song_description, uploaded_time, emotion, tempo,
    user, happiness, instruments, similar_artists, play_count,
    projects_count,
    rating, ratings_count, waveform, datasize, display_name, user_url, genre_id, 
    IF(user_ratings_count, 'User Voted', 'Not Voted') as voted 
FROM (
        SELECT  
            sp.songsID, projects_count, 
            AVG(rating) as rating,
            COUNT(rating) AS ratings_count,
            COUNT(IF(userid=$userid, 1, NULL)) as user_ratings_count

                FROM (
                    SELECT songsID, COUNT(*) as projects_count
                    FROM $sTable s
                    LEFT JOIN $sTable2 p ON s.songsID = p.songs_id

                    GROUP BY songsID) as sp

            LEFT JOIN $sTable3 r ON sp.songsID = r.songid           

            GROUP BY sp.songsID) as spr

LEFT JOIN $sTable6 gs ON gs.song_id = songsID  

JOIN $sTable s USING (songsID)
LEFT JOIN $sTable5 q ON s.user = q.ID
```

While this query is returning all the information from the various tables (all designates as $sTable, $sTable2, $sTable3 etc.) it is giving me duplicate rows based on $sTable6.

This only occurs with the $sTable6 JOIN in place, the line third from the bottom:

```
LEFT JOIN $sTable6 gs ON gs.song_id = songsID
```

With this line removed all is okay.  However I need to retrieve this information in order to provide dynamic filtering by the 'genre_id'.  Currently it retrieves all the rows from $sTable along with all the corresponding information from the other various tables, but also reprints any rows in $sTable that share the song_id/songsID with $sTable6.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: I can think of join order there and remember that left join is outer join and will return nulls if the match is not found. Or use group by to get rid of dups but as a last resort perhaps. Hope it helps.

Comment: which version of mysql are you using? I found this -- reading doc on 5.1 The columns of a NATURAL join or a USING join may be different from previously. Specifically, redundant output columns no longer appear, and the order of columns for SELECT * expansion may be different from before.

Comment: Thanks Sergey.  I had actually already tried using GROUP BY.  While this did indeed remove the duplicates as expected it also causes a syntax error in my WHERE clause later on for some reason.  I truly am at a loss to explain why

Comment: i'm using MYSQL version 5.0.92... Upgrading my verion IS an option if need be

Comment: so it could be the issue with the version previous to 5.1. I suggest you upgrade although they mean  The term “previously” means “prior to MySQL 5.0.12.” Which might not be the case but I would still recommend doing it.

Comment: Thanks sergey i'm actually goin to upgrade now.

Comment: Please write back if it solves it or.not

Comment: Okay I have managed to upgrade to MYSQL 5.1.56 (going straight to 5.5 is what caused me the problem before) however it hasn't solved my issue, I am still getting duplicate rows.

Comment: use LEFT JOIN (select distinct song_id,genreId from $sTable6) as gs on gs.song_id=songsId  ---- hope it helps

Comment: @Sergey Unfortunately no it hasn't helped.  I had already tried exactly that with SELECT DISTINCT.  I'm totally confused why this should be.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7086/discussion-between-sergey-benner-and-gordyr)

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate song_id's in the LEFT JOINed table.  I use something like the following to limit that JOIN to only one matching record:

EDITED:

```
LEFT JOIN $sTable6 gs ON gs.song_id = songsID AND gs.MYUNIQUECOLUMN IN (SELECT MYUNIQUECOLUMN FROM $sTable6 WHERE song_id = songsID ORDER BY MYUNIQUECOLUMN LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Thanks ElJay looks about right!  Unfortunately i cant test it as my mysql upgrade completely borked! worryingly i'm having trouble reinstalling it as i'm constantly getting package not found from the remi repo! *panic*

Comment: @gordyr, I am not familiar with MySQL installs on anything but Gentoo, so I can't help ya there.  I did fix the SQL above (it wouldn't have solved anything the way it was)

Comment: that will make you join only on 1 songId in this case first ordered. are you sure you want to do that? in this case I don't see the sense in the query at all because you will need the genreId for every selected songId not the only first one gotten from the table6. Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: No problem, i'm sure i'll get it sorted soonish... As soon as I do and I have tested your solution i'll mark the question as answered.  Huge thanks. :-)

Comment: how did you perform the upgrade? are you using CentOS/RHEL?

Comment: Phew... got it sorted, not being a server guy cPanel can be a lifesaver sometimes.  Unfortunately with my current version of mySQL your solution doesn't work, I get the error: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'. i'll try the upgrade again unless you have any other methods of achieving the same thing? Yes Sergey i'm on CentOs/Rhel

Comment: @Sergey - You are correct i will need it for every selected songid.  In my Mysql panic I didn't read over the suggestion thoroughly.

Comment: OK. Install new 5.1 do the mysqldump backup of old DB hope its not very big and restore it on the new one. it shouldn't take long to install it.

Comment: okay here goes it LEFT JOIN (select distinct songId,genreId from table6) as b on b.songsId=songsId

Comment: @ Sergey I now have 5.1.56 installed and operating correctly but unfortunately the duplicate row issue persists. see My comment above.

Comment: use the last JOIN query please. if it works give credit to ELJay because he gave the idea with duplicates in the table6. but he'll have to fix the answer then :)